# Passing NSString into UIAlertview's message content

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to display something like this: `SampleUser poked you.` in a `UIAlertView`'s `message`, but actually i'm getting errors. I know how to do it with a simple string, i don't know how to do it with a string that contains another string.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Poke" message:@"%@ poked you.", self.senderString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
[alertView show];
```

Comment: "but actually i'm getting errors" -- We're all very sorry to hear that.

Comment: @HotLicks i think in this case it was irrelevant to name the error, since the problem was obvious.

Comment: @vv88 While I agree that the problem was obvious, naming the error should never be considered irrelevant.  If the asker knows the error is irrelevant, then the asker should be able to easily answer his own question without posting to StackOverflow.  You should be posting to StackOverflow when the solution isn't obvious to you, and if the answer isn't obvious to you, you should include the error message.  For one, because you wouldn't be qualified to determine whether it's obvious to others (as it's not obvious to you) and for two, because it makes the error easier to spot.

Comment: And perhaps for three, it allows an answer like me to take the opportunity to explain not only what you did wrong but what the error message is trying to tell you so that in the future when you see the same error message in a different context you might more readily solve the problem on your own.

Comment: @nhgrif you are totally right, i thought where is the problem but didn't know it exactly how to solve it. I tried almost the same solutions, that you and sebastien posted, but couldn't figure out the right way. However i think the way that HotLicks indicated this issue was a little bit personal and also not a best behavior.

Comment: One of the most critical skills a programmer needs is the ability to to fully describe and characterize a problem.  You can't solve a problem if you can't describe it.  This includes collecting ALL the information that you have about the problem, including all error messages, exception traces, etc.

Comment: @HotLicks It's an advice that's worth sharing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that for the `message:` argument, you're attempting to send this:

```
@"%@ poked you.", userName
```

This doesn't make any sense.

Instead, you need to send an `NSString` object as the argument.

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ poked you.", self.senderString];
```

Now that we've created an `NSString` object, we can use this object as the message argument.

You could create this object embedded in the call to create the alert view, but for readability and debugging , it's better to do it this way.

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ poked you.", self.senderString];
UIAlertView *pokeAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Poke" 
                                                    message:message 
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
[pokeAlert show];
```

Comment: It's also a working, correct solution. I accepted the other question because it was posted sooner, but i also give +1, because it's totally deserved. Thank you.

Comment: That's fine, but just consider the other answer didn't really explain the problem/solution, moreover the other answer isn't actually completely correct and wouldn't work if you just copy & pasted it over.

Answer (score 4):

You should create your composed-`NSString` first and then call it in your `UIAlertView`:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ poked you.", userName];
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Poke" message:message, self.senderString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
[alertView show];
```

Comment: As @sebastien answered it is best to break compound statements into several individual statements. It is clearer, easier to debug and generally just as efficient in the final generated code. It will make your coding life easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Poke" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ poked you.", self.senderString] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
[alertView show];
```